# Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement' Error when trying to select a form in React JS and Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send FormData using Axios in a React JS app. This form should have text and multiple file inputs. When I tried to use querySelector to select the form it doesn’t seems to be working.

```
import axios from 'axios';

function Verify() {

    const form = document.querySelector("formElement");

    console.log(form) //This says Null

    const submitApplication = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(form);

        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/stats', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("Successfully Sent!")
        });
    };

    return (
        <>

            <form id="formElement" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="fname" />
                <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" />
                <button onClick={submitApplication} >Submit for Review</button>
            </form>

        </>
    );
}

export default Verify;
```

Below this the error message :

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'**

Comment: For `.querySelector()` to find an id, you have to use proper selector syntax: `.querySelector("#formElement")`

Comment: Also you can't find the form in the DOM until it is actually **added** to the DOM. The `.querySelector()` should be inside the submit callback function.

Comment: Thank you so much. Changing the placement of the function fixed the issue as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an HTML element by id using querySelector, you must prepend '#':

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#formElement");
```